# Onclick change paragraph content(in other div)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just learning the html, css, javascript stuff and I stuck on a point.
I have a webpage,designed by css.

How to click on the list item to change the PARAGRAPH only,but not the css designed (see picture)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs59U.jpg --
or --  i.stack.imgur.com/zs59U.jpg

the list is in:

```
<div id="bodyleft">
<h2>History</h2>
<li><a href="#">1996-2000</a></li>
```

the paragraph is:

```
<div id="bodyright">
<h2>blah blah blah blah blah blah </h2>
<p> blah blah blah....  </p> and I want thange THIS!!
```

I tried everything what I could ,but nothing works!
Please help me out!
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you need JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: _I tried everything what I could ,but nothing works!_ Soo - what was that?

Comment: By the way, at least post what have you tried instead of saying you tried *everything what you could*, since you're learning we don't know what's everything you know.

Comment: And please tell me how is this related to "Java" ?

Comment: Yeah,sorry for the mistakes. This is my first question,but can anyone help instead of flaming please?

Comment: Nobody is flaming, we're asking you *what have you tried* in order to provide you real advice.

Comment: I tried the getElementById() Method but Its not working,it's changing the whole dev stuff..but I want change the paragraph only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this

```
var ul = document.querySelector('#bodyleft ul');
ul.onclick = function(e){
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var p = document.querySelector('#bodyright p');
    p.innerHTML = 'Clicked on ' + target.innerHTML;
    return false;
};
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/gh5Tk/1/)

Comment: <title>SUM 41</title>
<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<SCRIPT LANGUGE="JavaScript">

var ul = document.querySelector('#bodyleft ul');
ul.onclick = function(e){
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var p = document.querySelector('#bodyright p');
    p.innerHTML = 'Clicked on ' + target.innerHTML;
    return false;
};

</script>



</head>

--Like this?

Comment: Put it inside `<script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function(){ // code goes here }</script>`, in `head` section.

Comment: Thank you very much  Sheikh Heera!!

Comment: Last question,I'm sorry if I bothering you. Is there any way to put a long text in the <p>? Because its not wraped. Or maybe load from txt file?

Comment: Yes, you can put long text in `p`, just use `p{ word-wrap: break-word; }` in `css`.

Comment: Thank you chief,you're the best! (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Get the p tags within the bodyright element.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('bodyright'),
    myP = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('p');
myP[0].innerHTML = 'hi there';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BJFVY/